# How "some_command | sudo tee" really works?

Tags: sudo, pipe, tee

I guess I know when there is a pipe (|) the left-side command is executed first and the result is passed to the right-side command of pipe but...

```
apt update | sudo tee
```

... how can work that way? there is any "syntactic sugar" involved?

Answer (score 2):

> when there is a pipe (|) the left-side command is executed first and the result is passed to the right-side command of pipe

*Incorrect*.

Both processes start off at the same time. So, in your example `apt update` and `sudo tee` starts at the same time, and the STDOUT of `apt update` is passed on the STDIN of `sudo tee`.

There is no syntactic sugar involved, anonymous pipe (`|`) is a common (and old) form of IPC in *nix.

FWIW, there's also another form of pipe IPC -- named pipe.

Comment: But... if it both process starts at the same time, then ... the left-side commando should be rejected first as is not authorized (it has no permissions / ownership to do that). Or not? please, elaborate.

Comment: @boctulus `apt update` should be terminated first because of permission, and that will make `sudo tee` to exit as well. OTOH, if the right-hand process dies first, the left one will get `SIGPIPE` when it tries to write to STDOUT and will be terminated unless it handles `SIGPIPE`.

Comment: But "apt update | sudo tee" works :) in a fresh terminal where a sudoers user is logged. So what?

You are incorrect.

Comment: @boctulus I didn't claim that it does not work, i only said which terminates when. Please read carefully.

Comment: Ok.. so how can that works? that is my question! how the left-side command can gain auth from right side command? what kind of messages are passed?

Comment: @boctulus The left hand command *does not* have permission and if you run without being superuser it will fail (unless you have done something weird with permissions of the `apt` binary). Please add the output in your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95016/discussion-between-boctulus-and-heemayl).